# Defective primary display.

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors

I have a SONY Vaio with a screen that's broken as I only see white or black dots on the display. I would like to have it start automatically to the external monitor but my previous computer settings for an external display has it set on "extended" rather than "duplicate". Therefore, whenever I boot up, I have the extended screen on the external, which does me no good since I can't really do anything with my start bar still located on the broken screen.

Are there any keystrokes for a Sony Vaio that will automatically let me duplicate screens or direct everything to the external?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Windows Vista, 7, or 8?

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will allow you to cycle through your screen settings. It will show up with a list of these options (this is the Windows 8 version):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fn+F7 should be your Function key combination to switch between laptop screen and external monitor.  You should be able to use that at boot to be able to see the BIOS and (immediately afterwards) the Windows Safe Mode menu on the External Monitor.

What I would do is hit F8 after the BIOS splash screen, call up the safe mode menu, boot to VGA mode.  Since your video card drivers won't be loaded at the settings you were using before, you won't be forcing the desktop to be extended onto the external monitor.  From there, you can reset the dual monitor configuration, and just reboot.

Comment: I tried hitting Fn+f7 previously and it kept giving me an error saying that "windows cannot operate under current configurations" (or something to that effect). This was when I had the external connected onto my laptop, with my laptop being black/broken and the external showing an empty extended screen.

Would you also happen to know any tricks for how to find windows in a screen? Is there a way to align the cursor? for example, the previous error message for ext config was only discovered after I tried blind dragging my mouse from the laptop to the ext screen many, many times. 

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not telling you to hit that key when in Windows.  The error you are getting at that point could be due to the external not being able to display a particular resolution.  No... I'm talking about hitting FN+F7 to be able to display the VAIO splash screen on the external monitor, and to be able to see the safe mode menu on that external as well.  This would be well before Windows boots.